# Is there a `connect()` implementation for `Iterator<Item=Str>`?

Tags: rust

Currently the [SliceConcatExt](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html) seems to be very specifically crafted for slices or vectors of Strings, even though it arbitrarily constrains its use. That particular use-case is reflected in the trait name as well, after all, it is called `SliceConcatExt` for a reason.

**Is there a more general `connect()` implementation which would take any Iterator over items supporting the Str trait ?**. 
If not, are there any plans to remedy this ?

### Example

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

fn connected<S, I>(s: I) -> String
where S: Str,
      I: IntoIterator<Item=S> {
    // have
    s.into_iter().collect::<Vec<S>>().connect(", ")

    // want
    // s.into_iter().connect(", ")
    // error: type `<I as core::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter` does not implement any method in scope named `connect`
    // tests/lang.rs:790         s.into_iter().connect(", ")
}

connected(&["foo", "bar"]);
```

One could possibly implement `SliceConcatExt` for any iterator with item type Str, but I have the suspicion that `connect()` currently is just unnecessarily specialized, which might be fixable until Rust beta.

Using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (522d09dfe 2015-02-19) (built 2015-02-19)`

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted on the rust bug tracker instead ?

Comment: I am not sure if it is intentional or not, as I always have to assume complete err on my side. If we conclude it is more like an API design issue, it should move on to the bug tracker indeed.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is indeed creating an issue on github about this, please CC me using @Byron. Thank you

Comment: Seems like it would be implementable for `IntoIterator`, yes. Maybe less efficiently, but implementable. I would encourage you to search the bug tracker for an issue on this, or open a new one

Comment: I have created a new issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest solution I know of would be to use [`Itertools::intersperse`](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse):

```
#![feature(core)]

extern crate itertools;

use std::iter::IntoIterator;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn connected<'a, S, I>(s: I) -> String //'
    where S: Str,
          I: IntoIterator<Item=&'a S> //'
{
    s.into_iter().map(|s| s.as_slice()).intersperse(", ").collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", connected(&["foo", "bar"]));
}
```

Comment: ah you got it working. Good to see where I got stuck.

Comment: That will do ! Thank you. I still think it's a usability issue, either solved by improving the docs, or ... just making the common string case easier (or more obvious) to use.

Comment: And also, isn't the livetime magic happening at `I: IntoIterator<Item=&'a S>` unnecessary for inputs like 'static strings ? If I remove it, and pass in a static str, it says it doesn't live long enough. Also I'd think that `S: Str + 'a` is the same, but more general, but it's not the case. Maybe something for another question though.